# boto get_assignments AWS.MechanicalTurk.HITDoesNotExist error

Tags: python, boto, mechanicalturk

I want to retrieve assignments from an old HIT on mturk using boto. This is what I did.

```
from boto.mturk.connection import MTurkConnection
import csv
mtc = MTurkConnection(aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_ID,
                                  aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,
                                  host=HOST)

assignments = mtc.get_assignments(HIT_ID, status=None, sort_by='SubmitTime', sort_direction='Ascending', page_size=10, page_number=1, response_groups=None)

with open('assignments.csv','w') as tar:
        csvwriter = csv.writer(tar, delimiter=';', quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONE, quotechar='')
        for asgn in assignments:
                row = []
                for i in range(len(asgn.answers[0])):
                        row.append(asgn.answers[0][i].fields[0])
                csvwriter.writerow(row)
```

But it is throwing this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "launch_task.py", line 13, in <module>
    assignments = mtc.get_assignments(HIT_ID, status=None, sort_by='SubmitTime', sort_direction='Ascending', page_size=10, page_number=1, response_groups=None)
  File "/home/projects/django_version/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/mturk/connection.py", line 417, in get_assignments
    [('Assignment', Assignment)])
  File "/home/projects/django_version/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/mturk/connection.py", line 838, in _process_request
    return self._process_response(response, marker_elems)
  File "/home/projects/django_version/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/mturk/connection.py", line 853, in _process_response
    raise MTurkRequestError(response.status, response.reason, body)
boto.mturk.connection.MTurkRequestError: MTurkRequestError: 200 OK
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<GetAssignmentsForHITResponse><OperationRequest>
<RequestId>b006785d-4001-4835-adf6-2df34joW9588e</RequestId></OperationRequest>
<GetAssignmentsForHITResult><Request><IsValid>False</IsValid>
<Errors><Error><Code>AWS.MechanicalTurk.HITDoesNotExist</Code>
<Message>Hit 3MRHU529465LUERYI53175P072A8 does not exist. (1463449047025 s)</Message>
<Data><Key>HITId</Key><Value>3MRHU529465LUERYI53175P072A8</Value></Data>
<Data><Key>HITId</Key><Value>3MRHU529465LUERYI53175P072A8</Value></Data>
</Error></Errors>
</Request></GetAssignmentsForHITResult></GetAssignmentsForHITResponse>
```

I assure you the HIT does exist. I am using boto 2.40.0 .

Comment: The most common reason for this is moving code from the MTurk sandbox to the live server, where HITIds are different. Another is that the HIT expired and was disposed of automatically after a period of inactivity. You might try a `search_hits()` or `get_all_hits()` call to check that the HITId actually is correct and the HIT is still around.

Comment: You also mention that it's an "old HIT" -- it'd help if you clarified how old (days, weeks, months, years)? At a certain point, I believe the HITs are no longer available for you to access (even if you didn't dispose of them).

Comment: Thanks @Thomas. You are correct. The HIT is more than a year old and I could not find it in 'get_all_hits()' list.

Comment: Thanks @jrb. You are right too.